# Pandas: Drop rows for IDs that do not exist for each year

Tags: python, pandas

My dataset contains information on banks from 2009 to 2019, but some banks were merged/acquired or closed along the way, so I would like to remove any banks that did not exist from 2009 to 2019. For example, ID 32 and 56 do not exist in 2019, therefore they should be dropped. Here is how my data look like:

```
ID  Assets  Year
32    10    2009
45    5     2009
56    24    2009
78    9     2009
32    11    2010
45    6     2010
56    31    2010
78    14    2010
...   ...   ...
32    11    2018
45    13    2018
78    14    2018
45    13    2019
78    3     2019
```

Since only ID 45 and 78 exists from 2009 to 2019, everything else should be dropped. Here is how it should look like:

```
ID  Assets  Year
45    5     2009
78    9     2009
45    6     2010
78    14    2010
...   ...   ...
45    13    2018
78    14    2018
45    13    2019
78    3     2019
```

Comment: do you have the list of banks that you need to drop or do you need to figure that out too?

Comment: I unfortunately do not have a list of the banks...

Comment: then how do you want to filter them?  just banks that exist in 2019?  what is the condition for knowing that a bank still exists?

Comment: If it is possible, I would like banks that existed from 2009 to 2019, so if a bank was created in 2012 even though it still exists in 2019, it should be dropped.

Comment: so a bank that has id in every single year?

Comment: Correct! I should have been more clear, my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you have a list of bank ids that are closed:

```
closed = [56, 32]

df[~df['ID'].isin(closed)]
```

in reverse, assuming you have a list of existin banks:

```
opened = [45, 78]

df[df['ID'].isin(opened)]
```

**EDITED BASED ON QUESTION CLARIFICATION**

data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Assets': {0: 10, 1: 5, 2: 24, 3: 9, 4: 11, 5: 6, 6: 31, 7: 14, 8: 11, 9: 13, 10: 14, 11: 13, 12: 3},
 'ID': {0: 32, 1: 45, 2: 56, 3: 78, 4: 32, 5: 45, 6: 56, 7: 78, 8: 32, 9: 45, 10: 78, 11: 45, 12: 78},
 'Year': {0: 2009, 1: 2009, 2: 2009, 3: 2009, 4: 2010, 5: 2010, 6: 2010, 7: 2010, 8: 2018, 9: 2018, 10: 2018, 11: 2019, 12: 2019}})
```

if you need to get a list of ids that were available in every year:

```
## number of unique years each id needs to have:
year_count = len(df['Year'].unique())

## get number of unique years that each id has:
id_year_count = df[['Year','ID']].groupby(['ID', 'Year']).count().reset_index().groupby('ID').count().reset_index()

## filter to get the list of ids that match the condition:
opened_every_year = id_year_count['ID'][id_year_count['Year']==year_count].tolist()

## pass the list to the df to filter as described before
df = df[df['ID'].isin(opened_every_year)]
```

To check:

`df.sort_values(['ID', 'Year'])`

outputs:

```
    Assets  ID  Year
1        5  45  2009
5        6  45  2010
9       13  45  2018
11      13  45  2019
3        9  78  2009
7       14  78  2010
10      14  78  2018
12       3  78  2019
```

(Note that data sample only had data for 4 years, so it selected ids with all 4 years)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I got the result I was looking for!

Comment: Glad to help.  Please upvote and accept the answer :)